# Algorithm runtime

Tags: algorithm, runtime

[image]

Can you please help me with calculating the running time of this function?

My guess would be O(n log n)
n for the for-loop, and log n for the while loop.

But what makes me unsure is the j = j*3. 
if it would have been j = j/2, then I would have been sure of my answer.

Is it log n even though it is j = j*3 or j = j/3?

Comment: Sorry, for that. I have updated the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's `j = j*3`, then the complexity will just be `O(n*log_3(n))` instead of `O(n*log_2(n))` for `j = j*2` because they only differ by a constant factor which will be absorbed under `Big-O` notation.

Coming to your function, the outer loop is surely `O(n)` but the inner loop is not completely `log_3(n)` every time. It's actually decreasing with every iteration. The expansion will be:

```
log_3(n) + log_3(n-1) + log_3(n-2) + ... + log_3(1)
```

Ignoring bases because of the reason explained above, we can write:

```
log(n) + log(n-1) + log(n-2) + ... + log(1)
```

- One method to evaluate this is to upper bound each of the above terms by `log(n)`, i.e.,

  ```
  log(n) + log(n-1) + log(n-2) + ... + log(1) <= log(n) + log(n) + log(n) + ... + log(n)
                                              <= n*log(n)
  ```

  Thus, the complexity can be written as **`O(n*log(n))`**.
- Second method is as follows. Rewriting the above equation, we have:

  ```
  log(n) + log(n-1) + log(n-2) + ... + log(1)
  = log(n*(n-1)*(n-2)...1)
  = log(n!)
  ```

  Thus, for sure, the complexity can be written as `O(log(n!))`. But what about `log(n!)`? According to [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),

  ```
  log(n!) ~ n*log(n) - n + O(log(n))
  ```

  Note that, according to Wikipedia:

  > It is a **very powerful approximation**, leading to **accurate results even for small values of n**.

  Thus, I can assume that this will be very much accurate for large values of `n` (the case that we actually care about). Clearly, in the above approximation, the value of `n*log(n)` dominates the other terms, thus, in `Big-O` notation, I can write:

  ```
  O(log(n!)) = O(n*log(n))
  ```

Comment: Okey, thanks for the answer.
I have one more question that I hope you can answer. When is it root(n) ? What kind of function has that as running time?

Comment: @KunoHeltborg When you run the inner loop for `root(n)` times for a given `n`.

Comment: Can you please come with a example. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The answer by Yair Twito (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38974663/1400793) below is better than this -- it correctly gives the complexity as Theta(n).

Answer (score 1):

A tighter upper-bound would be O(n).
Because the total time is ( Sum(i=1 to n) of (log(n/i)) ) = log(n^n/n!) = O(n)
The running time is actually Θ(n) if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity of nested loops is equal to the number of times the **innermost** statement is executed. For example :

```
   for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i ++ ) {
   for ( int j = 1; j <= n; j ++ ) {
      // O(1) expressions
   }
```

}

In this situation (log_3(n)) you can test it with a small c++ code like this:

```
int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int j;
    int count = 0;
    int totalCount = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= N; i++ ) {
        j = i;
        while ( j <= N ) {
            j = j * 3;
            count++;
        }
        std::cout << " " << i <<"th iteration of outer loop : inner loop will iterate " << count << " times" << std::endl;
        totalCount += count;
        count = 0;
    }
    std::cout << "TOTAL COUNT is : " << totalCount << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Where you get results like this:

```
1th iteration of outer loop : inner loop will iterate 3 times
2th iteration of outer loop : inner loop will iterate 2 times
3th iteration of outer loop : inner loop will iterate 2 times
4th iteration of outer loop : inner loop will iterate 1 times
5th iteration of outer loop : inner loop will iterate 1 times
6th iteration of outer loop : inner loop will iterate 1 times
7th iteration of outer loop : inner loop will iterate 1 times
8th iteration of outer loop : inner loop will iterate 1 times
9th iteration of outer loop : inner loop will iterate 1 times
10th iteration of outer loop : inner loop will iterate 1 times
TOTAL COUNT is : 14
```

Comment: did you mean SquareRoot(N) complexity?

Comment: if yes ? there are many like : Find if a number is prime or not.
Grover's Algorithm: allows search (in quantum context) on unsorted input in time proportional to the square root of the size of the input. Factorization of the number.

Comment: yes, I mean squareroot, I am not interested in algorithms. Can you just give me a example of a Pseudocode? I just want to know what the running time looks like in code.

Comment: It is not clear yet. Are you need to know a complexity of algorithms that calculate squareroot of N or algorithms family have a complexity proportional to squareroot of input size?

Comment: int main() {

    int N = 123 * 123;
    int i = 1;
    int S = 0;

    while(S <= N) {
        S += 2*i + 1;
        i++;
    }

    std::cout << "Total iterations : " << i - 1<< std::endl;
}